# Android Context is become null

Tags: java, android

In my application

the class central is instantiate as like below :

central.java :

```
mContext = getApplicationContext();
mMyStuff = new MyStuff(mContext);
```

MyStuff class need to get the mContext to access from some resources.

MyStuff.java :

```
public class MyStuff {

    private Context  mContext;

    public MyStuff(Context c) {
        mContext = c;
    }

    ....    
    private ActionCustom MyAction = new ActionCustom(mContext);
```

issue is that mContext is always null even in c is not null. I was expecting that when doing the new MyStuff(mContext)

Answer (score 6):

> issue is that mContext is always null even in c is not null

Because currently :

```
private ActionCustom MyAction = new ActionCustom(mContext);
```

line executed before calling `MyStuff` class constructor where initialization of `mContext` object is done .

Do it as:

```
private ActionCustom MyAction;
public MyStuff(Context c) {
    mContext = c;
    MyAction = new ActionCustom(mContext);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Instead of

```
public MyStuff(Context c) {
    mContext = c;
}
```

try

```
public MyStuff(Context c) {
    this.mContext = c;
}
```

Comment: Sorry but it's not working. I have put a breakpoint on this.mContext = c but it never stop

Comment: What's the different between "mContext = c" and "this.mContext = c" in this case ?

Comment: Mystuff is non-static. Doing mContext = c would change it for every instance, and not for just *this* instance